# Does $X\cdot\langle2\rangle\cdot\langle3\rangle$ cover $\Bbb Z\left[\frac16\right]\cap(0,\infty)$? Is there a similar method using a Cantor set?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, covering-spaces, cantor-set

> Does the set given by $X\cdot\langle2\rangle\cdot\langle3\rangle$ exactly cover $\Bbb Z\left[\frac16\right]\cap(0,\infty)$?  Is there a similar method using a Cantor set?

Where $X=\{x\in\Bbb N:x\equiv\pm1\pmod 6\}$ and $\langle p\rangle=\{p^i:i\in\Bbb Z\}$

I think it does because if we exclude from the positive integers the multiples of $2$ and $3$, we get the numbers equivalent to $\pm1\pmod 6$ then reintroducing the factors $2^i\cdot3^i$ restores $\Bbb N>0$ and also all the dyadic and ternary denominators.

Is there a similar cover using the middle two-thirds Cantor set $C_{2/3}$ in place of $X$?  The middle two-thirds Cantor set is the set of strings in base $6$ constructed out of 5s and 0s, so ends in $\pm1$. So I imagine there is some similar way of constructing $\Bbb Z[\frac16]$ using $C_{2/3}$, $\langle2\rangle$ and $\langle3\rangle$.

Obviously a direct replacement doesn't work but is there a relatively simple way of swapping the Cantor set in, such as e.g. a sum of two cantor sets?

Answer (score 3):

Yes $X.\langle2\rangle.\langle3\rangle$ covers $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{6}] \cap (0, \infty)$. You can show this bit pretty easily by seeing that any element $x \in \mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{6}] \cap (0, \infty)$ will be of the form $\frac{z}{6^n} = \frac{2^a3^bz'}{6^n} = 2^{a'}3^{b'}z'$ (where $z'$ and 6 are coprime), which cleary are contained in $X.\langle2\rangle.\langle3\rangle$.

Comment: For the cantor set query, I think the only way to do it would be to consider constructions like taking additive closure of $\mathbb{Z}.C_{2/3}$ or using X and $\langle2\rangle$ and $\langle3\rangle$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}$ which would essentially be constructing $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{6}]$ in a round about way without much depth.

Comment: Thank-you. I only now saw your comment. If you ping a user with @ then their username, they get notified of your comments. No need to ping the OP who is always pinged anyway. I'm not sure what you mean about the additive closure of $\mathbb{Z}\cdot C_{2/3}$.  Are you saying the additive closure of $C_{2/3}\cdot\langle2\rangle\cdot\langle3\rangle$ would be $\Bbb Z[\frac16]$?